# Protractor - Can't select an item from drop-down angular list

Tags: jquery, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I've tried to select the second item through an Angular drop-down list but the webdriver doesn't find this element.

**Error:**

```
NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.cssSelector("[ng-click=\"setCustomMode()\"]") at new bot.Error (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\error.js:113:18) at C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:706:15 at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1877:20) at [object Object].promise.Callback_.goog.defineClass.notify (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:2464:25) at [object Object].promise.Promise.notify_ (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:563:12) at Array.forEach (native) at Object.goog.array.forEach (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\array\array.js:203:43) at [object Object].promise.Promise.notifyAll_ (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:552:16) at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:125:21) at runMicrotasksCallback (node.js:337:7) Error at [object Object].ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:403:21) at [object Object].self.(anonymous function) [as isDisplayed] (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:76:19) at [object Object].self.(anonymous function) [as isDisplayed] (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:733:11) at [object Object]. (C:\automation\tests\testCases\newApp\newBtnTC.js:111:16) at C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd\index.js:94:14 at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1877:20) at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runEventLoop_ (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1755:8) at [object Object]. (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:2056:12) at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:125:21) at runMicrotasksCallback (node.js:337:7) From: Task: Asynchronous test function: it() at [object Object]. (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd\index.js:93:33) at [object Object]. (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\async-callback.js:45:37) at [object Object].jasmine.Block.execute (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:1174:17) at [object Object].jasmine.Queue.next_ (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2209:31) at [object Object].jasmine.Queue.start (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2162:8) at [object Object].jasmine.Spec.execute (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2503:14) at [object Object].jasmine.Queue.next_ (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2209:31) at onComplete (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2205:18) at [object Object].jasmine.Spec.finish (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2477:5) at [object Object].onComplete (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2504:10)==== async task ==== Error at [object Object]. (C:\automation\tests\testCases\newApp\newBtnTC.js:110:4) at [object Object].jasmine.Env.describe_ (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:913:21) at [object Object].jasmine.Env.describe (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:898:15) at describe (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:658:27) at Object. (C:\automation\tests\testCases\newApp\newBtnTC.js:1:63) at Module._compile (module.js:460:26) at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10) at Module.load (module.js:355:32) at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on this line:

```
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf($$("k-list-container.k-popup.k-group.k-reset")), 30000);
```

The `visibilityOf` expected condition expects an `ElementFinder` to be passed in. Use:

```
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf($("k-list-container.k-popup.k-group.k-reset")), 30000);
```

---

Also, I think you are missing the dot at the beginning of the selector, since `k-list-container` is one of the classes:

```
.k-list-container.k-popup.k-group.k-reset
```

And, even the fixed selector is not going to work. Here is what is working for me:

```
element(by.model("selectedService")).click().then(function () {
    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf($("md-select-menu md-option")), 30000);
    $$("md-select-menu md-option").get(1).click();
    browser.driver.sleep(2000);
});
```

Comment: Still doesn't find this element. I've update my post and added all the previous steps and the global variable

Comment: @IdanE yeah, this would help to avoid the error you had. What is the error now? Thanks.

Comment: Please take a look in the error again, I've updated it.

Comment: Me neither, anyway I've tried to put this var in comment but it was still failed, now because Error: Wait timed out after 30039ms

Comment: @IdanE okay, let me try reproduce your problem locally.

Comment: Thanks a lot,
You're a super brilliant as always!

Comment: @IdanE sorry for multiple attempts, tried to solve it without actually running the test. Thanks!